# redux form input custom component not submitting

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a custom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const InputText = ({ value, onChange, name }) =>
    {
        return(<StyledInput value={value} onChange={() => onChange(value)}/>)
    }



const StyledInput =  styled.input.attrs({
    type: 'text',
    name: props => props.name,
  value: props => props.value,
  placeholder: props => props.placeholder,
    width: props => props.width,
    onChange: props => props.onChange,
})`
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  margin: 8px 5px 3px 8px;
  width: ${props => props.width || 275}px;
`;

export default InputText
```

that I am using in a Redux form:

```
const CreateNewAssignmentForm  = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, closeModal } = props
  return(<div>
    <Modal id="AssignmentModal">
      <ModalBody width={600}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextRight>
          <CloseIconButton stroke={color.primary} onClick={() => closeModal()} />
        </TextRight>

        <Box pad={{ left: 30 }}>
          <FormTitle> Add Assignment</FormTitle>
        </Box>

        <Box pad={{ left: 40, top: 10 }}>
          <StyledFormSubHeading>Essay Settings</StyledFormSubHeading>
         <Split>
           <StyledFormLabel>Essay Title</StyledFormLabel>
           <StyledFormLabel>Select Template</StyledFormLabel>
         </Split>
         <Split>
           <Field name="title" component={InputText} type="text" placeholder="Title" />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </Split>
       </Box>
       </form>
     </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
  </div>)
}
```

From the redux form documentation, it says that the `value` and `onChange` props should be passed for custom components to work. But when I try this, I get a `TypeError: _onChange is not a function` error

if I omit the onChange event, the input works, but when I submit the form, the input is not present in the data returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upon more careful reading of the documentation, the props should be input.value and input.onChange, like so:

```
const InputText = ({ input: { value, onChange }, width, placeholder  }) =>
    {
        return(<StyledInput value={value} onChange={onChange} />)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

same as snowflakekiller.

If you want to use the Field on a component only trigger props.onChange but without trigger props.input.onChange, you can extend it:

```
import {TextArea} from 'react-weui';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class MyTextArea extends TextArea {
    handleChange(e) {
        super.handleChange(e);
        if (this.props.input && this.props.input.onChange)     this.props.input.onChange(e);
    }
}

...

<Field component={MyTextArea} name='xxx' placeholder="Enter lettering" rows="3" 
    maxLength={200}></Field>
```